# Solve $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ given $x(12-x)+y(16-y)=100$.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, square-numbers

> Solve the equation in $\mathbb{R}$
> $$x(12-x)+y(16-y)=100$$

**MY IDEAS:**

\begin{aligned}
& x(12-x)+y(16-y)=100 \\
& 12 x-x^2+y^{16}-y^2=100 \\
& 12 x+16 y-x^2-y^2=100 \\
& 12 x+16 y-x^2-y^2-100=0 \\
& -12 x-16 y+x^2+y^2+100=0 \\
& x^2+y^2+100=+12 x+16 y=12 x+16 y \\
& 2 x^2+2 y^2+100-x^2-y^2=12 x+16 y
\end{aligned}

This is all I could thought of. I tried in the last part to use the formula

$a^{2}-b^{2}=(a+b)(a-b)$

I don't know how to continue! Any ideas are welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Hint: use $(x-6)^2$ and $(y-8)^2.$

Comment: Solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ using the quadratic equation formula (treating $x$ as a constant and $y$ as the variable being solved for in terms of $x$). Find out for what values of $x$ is $y$ a real number by observing when the discriminant (which is a function of $x$) is non-negative.

Comment: To expand on Ryszard's comment, try completing the square to put the equation in the form $(x - 6)^2 + (y - 8)^2 = c$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Wow! You are fast!  I understand it using your idea! Thank you sooo much from the bottom of my heart!!!

Comment: @AnnieCarter isn't equal to 0? like c=0

Comment: @AnnieCarter so that means that x=6 and y=8

Comment: Yup, you got it!

Comment: You welcome. In this case you got $c=0$ following the notation by @AnnieCarter But even with $c>0$ the solution would be $x=6+\sqrt{c}\cos t$ and $y=8+\sqrt{c}\sin t$ for $0\le t<2\pi.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a completing the square exercise. So first you open the brackets, then you complete the square, and then the answer is obvious.
$$x(12-x) + y(16-y) = -(x^2 - 12x)-(y^2-16y) = -((x-6)^2-36)-((y-8)^2 - 64)=\
-(x-6)^2 + 36 -(y-8)^2 + 64 = 100 \\
\Rightarrow
-(x-6)^2 -(y-8)^2 + 100 = 100\\
\Rightarrow (x-6)^2 + (y-8)^2 = 0
$$
Note that the sum of squares is positive unless each of the squares is zero. Hence the unique answer ix $x=6, y=8$

Comment: I would never thought of this! Also you are really fast! :)) Thank you so much!!!